# WPF binding: SelectedItem and SelectedIndex not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, touch

First of all this is not a binding or general problem. The sample works fine on several machines but one!
I put a trace into my functions so I can see when the properties set is called. Both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` are not working on
Windows 7 Embedded Standard with Elo Touchscreen.
I think either "Embedded" or "Touchscreen" are the reason to fail.

Does anybody have an idea?

Here's my sample code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DialogProperties}, Path=ListArticle}"
         SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource DialogProperties}, Path=ItemIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource DialogProperties}, Path=Article, Mode=TwoWay}" 
>
```

with this ViewModel:

```
public  IEnumerable<Article>  ListArticle { get; private set; }
public  Article  _Article = null;
public  Article  Article
{
    get { return _Article; }
    set {
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("SetArticle..");
        _Article = value;
    }
}
public  int  _ItemIndex = 0;
public  int  ItemIndex 
{
    get { return _ItemIndex; }
    set {
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("SetItemIndex");
        _ItemIndex = value;
    }
}
```

**Update (09/14/2015):**
I added the SelectionChanged event handler to the listbox and it fires as expected on both machines.

Please note: I could easily create a workaround to solve that Problem. But I'm using the "Infragistics WPF Framework" and it's impossible to fix or check every occurrence there!

**Update (09/16/2015):**
All test environments use the latest .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: What is the reason to bind SelectedIndex, when you already bind SelectedItem?

Comment: Are you sure the item is selected and not just focussed?

Comment: @Clemens: Just to demonstrate neither works.

Comment: @Wouter: Good idea! I'll check wheter the Events are fired.

Comment: @Wouter:  I added the SelectionChanged event handler to the listbox and it fires as expected on both machines. See update above.

Comment: To be completely safe you could implement the INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Wouter: INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented for other properties. But it makes no difference, because PropertyChanged will only be called, when the setter is called!

Comment: Did you check the .net framework version on the embedded device? Maybe it's the .net framework client profile?

Comment: @Wouter: Yes, after realizing the reason I updated .NET Framework on that machine.